# Azure scale set how to enable outbound connectivity after adding internal load balancer?

Tags: azure

I found one answer which was for standalone virtual machines: "To make outgoing connections it is necessary to create a second Load Balancer with a public IP with the same backend pool and a dummy rule with a dummy probe. Once the rule is created then it will trigger the creation of an outbound SNAT."

However, it looks that this does not work with scale set. Is there any workaround for this? I have having to route traffic from Azure firewall to public load balancer.

Comment: can you clarify this a bit, outbound* connectivity is there by default

Comment: I should have specified that the outbound connectivity in this case is internet. I can connect to virtual network just fine. Everything works well with scale set but if I add standard load balancer the internet connectivity disappears.

Comment: i dont see any evidence of what you are saying in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections). and i dont remember my vms losing outbound connectivity

Comment: "Standard Load Balancer and Standard Public IP introduce new abilities and different behaviors to outbound connectivity." I believe this is the thing that is affecting scale set as well.

Comment: sure, but nothing in standard lb blocks outbound connectivity. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#preventoutbound

Comment: Well even so the outbound connectivity stops after putting standard lb in front of vmss

Comment: ah, ok, i think i'm starting to see where it goes. its a standard INTERNAL lb, right? you'd need to create and assign second lb (not internal) and [configure outbound rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-rules-overview)

Comment: Yes it is standard internal LB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found ready made templates from someones github (https://github.com/MarekLani/AzureServiceFabricWithLoadBalancerStandard/blob/master/ServiceFabric.json). These seem to be working well for my cause.